# How to stop the vue component to not call mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

This is my mixin

```js
export default {
  created () {
    if (!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      this.$router.replace('/start')
    }
  }
}
```

This is my component:

```js
import Auth from '../auth'
   
export default {
  mixins: [Auth],
  computed: {
    orders () {
      return this.$store.getters.orders
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getOrders')
  }
}
```

Store:-

```js
async getOrders ({ commit, state }) {
  const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/orders`, {
    headers: {
      'authorization': state.currentUser.token
    }
  })
  commit('setOrders', res.data)
}
```

The problem I am facing is, although it does redirect to `'/start'` when I go to `'/orders'`, but it also start fetching the orders from `mounted` hook, and since `currentUser` is null it is giving a `TypeError` that `Cannot read property 'token' of null`. Although I can guard my `getOrders` function with a check if `currentUser` is set or not, but then I have to do it in many other functions. What I would like to happen is that after `created` hook mounted should not get called or any other technique anyone know better?

Comment: You should put a check for `currentUser` inside `getOrders`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking it the user is authenticated in a mixin use  [global navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-resolve-guards).

You can either use `beforeEach` or `beforeResolve` to check if the `currentUser` is not null.

```js
import store from './store'; // import your Vuex store

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    name: 'orders',
    path: '/orders',
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true // use this in the routes that need your currentUser
    }
  }],
});

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated || !store.state.currentUser) {
      next({
        name: 'forbidden' // the route the guest will be redirected to
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use route function `beforeRouteEnter`, if app has't authed, you can redirect to other page before enter the page need auth